What is the correct way to give permissions to access BigQuery's TABLE_STORAGE_BY_ORGANIZATION?
I am reading this doc and started writing a DBT model to make use of this view.
TABLE_STORAGE_BY_ORGANIZATION (links points to the required permission section)
My problem is that the required permissions assume it's "okay" to give these roles at Organization level, but I really hate it because, in our case, we have Service accounts that build our DBT models, and I don't want to give them the permission to query all the tables in our Organization.
It its my understanding that if I give a role like roles/bigquery.dataViewer to my service account, since this view is not bound to a dataset, I am not able to define a fine grained IAM permission that gives data to that specific table, in a specific view, in a specific project.
Do you know of a way to give the dataViewer Role only on that view ? (I guess I would also need to give permission to the tables used in the view)
I can assign the role in GCP IAM, or in Terraform.

Why don't you follow an easy way on this by creating a dataset that includes a sub of the views you want here with the fields required and then you can give the per dataset permission to the user or the service account you have

That sounds like a good idea. I don't know how to execute it. Can you elaborate please ?
This table that I am referring to is a metadata view provided by GCP at the organization level.
It's a view that I can query in the BQ console because I know its path, but I don't know a way to display it in the BigQuery UI table browser on the left panel for example.
Are you suggesting that I can "move" or copy, or sync this view to a dataset that I would create ?

The view called INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_BY_ORGANIZATION is, by definition, a view on your whole organization. Reading the docs, it looks like you can give the SA BigQuery Metadata Viewer (not Data Viewer) and you will still work.
Another thought, use the view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE ... this is qualified on a per project basis ... and hence you can refine which projects your SA can interrogate as opposed to the whole org.

@MiniYuuzhan Create a shared dataset in BigQuery and Views under it querying the tables you need along with the columns required. Then, give access to the views or the shared dataset to only the service account or the user you need. You can follow the steps in this link to try it out.
